# Qt- unable to save jpeg files

Tags: qt

I am trying to save images in Qt. I am able to save all the formats except jpeg. I have the following libraries under the plugins/imageformats folder.

libqgif.so, 
libqjpeg.so.

Do I have to place them in a different folder to make this work? Is there any new libraries that I have to install to make this work. I work on linux platform and my application is supported on all linux platforms. 
So do I have to install separate libraries for each platform?

Thanks,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might find what the problem is by:

- Setting the environment variable `QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS` to 1 before running your application.

  It will print the plugin loading attempts/successes/failures on the console.
- Using a [`QImageWriter`](http://doc.trolltech.com/latest/qimagewriter.html) to get a more explicit error message than with just `QImage::save` or `QPixmap::save` :

  ```
  QImageWriter writer("/tmp/test.jpg");
  if(!writer.write(pixmap.toImage()))
  {
      qDebug() << writer.errorString();
  }
  ```

Answer (score 4):

Under windows the `qjpeg4.dll` must in a `imageformats` directory under the application's directory by default.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding the following line to your main:

```
QApplication::addLibraryPath( <path to directory containing libjpeg.so> );
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if the linking in the .so files are proper.