# QImage: auto detect format when loading image

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qimage

I have an image with `.jpg` extension but it is stored as `png` format. When I use `QImage` to load that image, it returns an invalid `QImage`:

```
QImage image (path);
if (image.isNull())
{
    //it enters here
}
```

I have to check format one by one before loading image:

```
auto readImage = [](const QString & path)
{
    std::string formats[] = {
        "PNG",
        "JPG",
        "GIF",
        "JPEG",
    };

    for (auto && format : formats)
    {
        QImageReader img(path, format.c_str());
        if (img.canRead())
        {
            return QImage(path, format.c_str());
        }
    }
    return QImage(path);
};

QImage image = readImage(path);
if (image.isNull())
{
    //it does not enter here this time
}
```

Is there any better way to load image with unknown format?

Update using `load` method of `QImage`, still get the same result:

```
QImage image;
image.load(path);
if (image.isNull())
{
    //it enters herer
 }
```

Comment: `if (image.isNull())` or `if(!image.isNull())`?

Comment: @eyllanesc please read the question carefully before comment. There is nothing wrong with the current method. But in the future, if there is a new format, I have to add it into format list. `if (image.isNull())` of  course.

Comment: if there is a new format then you must create a plugin and embed it in Qt.

Comment: If there is a new image format and Qt can read it, you should be in the following list:http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qimagereader.html#supportedImageFormats

Comment: No, should be this one http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qimagereader.html#supportedImageFormats

Comment: I already corrected the link immediately after the publication, update the page :)

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you need (from [QImage documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qimage.html#load)):

> bool QImage::load(const QString &fileName, const char *format = nullptr)
>   Loads an image from the file with the given fileName. Returns true if the image was successfully loaded; otherwise invalidates the image and returns false.
>   The loader attempts to read the image using the specified format, e.g., PNG or JPG. **If format is not specified (which is the default), it is auto-detected based on the file's suffix** and header. For details, see {QImageReader::setAutoDetectImageFormat()}{QImageReader}.

If not, try looking at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14878670/qt-does-not-load-jpg-just-png) which mentions the option
that the jpeg plugin is missing? maybe try the exact same experiment with a *.png file?

Comment: should be this doc (http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qimage.html#QImage-8), but it still returns invalid `QImage`. That's why I have to manually specify image format

Comment: @PhạmAnhTuấn 
Does the file extension match the format of the image? I mean, many times on the internet I downloaded images with jpg extension that are really png.

Comment: The construction seems to be different than the load operation ... did you try both? if so, could you please add the load attempt to your post? thanks!